# How can I get the height of select2 drop-down?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am trying to get select2 drop-down actual rendered height, but:

If i use something like this:

```
$('#my-input-s2').on('select2-open', function() {
    var height = $(".my-dropdown").first().height()
    console.log(height)
  })
```

The result is always 29

And when i use this(because select2 is not fullly open because of reading remote data:

```
 $('#my-input-s2').on('select2-open', function() {
    var height = setTimeout($(".my-dropdown").first().height(),0)
    console.log(height)
  })
```

I result is gradually increasing value on every open of select2 (eg. 102, then 109, then 114)

But I need to determine the height of dropdown when the select2 is fully open
* edit (fully open = when the openning is done)
Thanx for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

Hang it to another event:

***select2-highlight***
Fired when a choice is highlighted in the dropdown.

```
$('#my-input-s2').on('select2-highlight', function() {
            var height = $(".my-dropdown").height()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a set value? The select2 CSS says:

```
.select2-results {
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
    position: relative;
}
```

So the height of a fully open dropdown box is 200px (+8 margin).

Comment: Yes, but this is max-height, but if the result is only eg. 3 options the actual height is smaller

Comment: then I don't understand your question, sorry. From your post you know and can get the height, and you are explicitly asking for the height when it's fully open, which I answered...

Comment: OK, sorry I need to get the actual height of dropdown, not the max height from css. (I mean fully open = when the openning is done)